# Any free/non-free Windows programs out there to emulate as physical optical drive?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, emulator, optical-media

My HP notebook dont have any optical drive. currently Windows 7 & Windows 10(x64) are installed back to back. So I am seeking for one which the OS would recognize as a optical drive & that is simply not just for mounting any ISO but doing other simulation jobs also. I tried a couple of programs but none showing as optical drive on Windows explorer. Is there any such software?

Comment: Your question is too vague. May you please give some examples of simulation jobs.

Comment: @NickDelta e.g Cannot make own Windows10 system repair disc(on GUI) since there is no such in my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Voila! the program **Virtual CD** did the job. https://www.virtualcd-online.com/ Got a clue here.. https://superuser.com/questions/183865/is-there-a-free-program-to-emulate-a-dvd-writer & [Virtual DVD/CD writer to emulate a physical writer and writable disk?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/735/virtual-dvd-cd-writer-to-emulate-a-physical-writer-and-writable-disk) 
My system *screenshots*..
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gt9i7.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pv9FU.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmFG2.jpg
Then need some adjustments in the settings & you are ready to go.